# Translate C++ map to python dictionary

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to translate an if-else statement written in c++ to a corresponding chunk of python code. For a C++ map dpt2, I am attempting to translate:

```
if (dpt2.find(key_t) == dpt2.end()) { dpt2[key_t] = rat; }
else { dpt2.find(key_t) -> second = dpt2.find(key_t) -> second + rat; }
```

I'm not super familiar with C++, but my understanding is that the -> operator is equivalent to a method call for a class that is being referenced by a pointer. My question is how do I translate this code into something that can be handled by an OrderedDict() object in python?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, in C++ you'd write that as:

```
dpt[key_t] += rat;
```

That will do only one map lookup - as opposed to the code you wrote which does 2 lookups in the case that `key_t` isn't in the map and 3 lookups in the case that it is.

---

And in Python, you'd write it much the same way - assuming you declare `dpt` to be the right thing:

```
dpt = collections.defaultdict(int) 
...
dpt[key_t] += rat
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't write the original code, so much of my problems with this is trying to understand janky code!

Comment: That transformation only works if `mapped_type{} + rat == mapped_type{rat}`. Of course that should be the case, but some people do weird stuff with operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
dpt2[key_t] = dpt2.get(key_t, 0) + rat
```